# Android TextInputLayout with EditText in ScrollView hides hint on focus

Tags: android, scrollview, hint, textinputlayout

if I focus a EditText within a ScrollView this happens (thats fine):
[image]

Then, I focus the EditText below and refocus EditText from picture one, then this happens:
[image]

The hint is not shown or badly (depending on scrollview).

Part of the solution:
The Scrollview sees that I want to focus the EditText but not the surrounded android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout element. Therefore it does not care if the hint is being shown.

How to fix?
My XML (basically a scrollview with some linearlayouts containing android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout with EditTexts):

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:weightSum="9"
                    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="hint1.1"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:hint="hint1.2"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="9"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="2"
                        android:gravity="center"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="hint2.1"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:hint="hint2.2"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="9"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="3"/>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:hint="hint3.1"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="4">

                        <EditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:hint="hint3.2"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:inputType="number"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: i think it is shown, but you can't see cuz scroll view is scrolled.

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to make the scrollview scroll properly?

Comment: try this code.. 
`your_scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                your_scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom());
            }
        });`

Comment: I wrote that code based on your answer and it works like a charm!
Thank you, @sourabh!
`EDITTEXT.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override public void run() {
                            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, textInputLayout.getTop());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code to scroll to proper position of your edittext view,

```
your_scrollview.post(new Runnable() { 
@Override
 public void run() { 
       your_scrollview.smoothScrollTo(0, your_EditBox.getBottom());
 } 
});
```